# Hotel Wi-Fi connection intermittently stops working

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point, wifi-configuration

I'm at a hotel and they have wonderful, fast Wi-Fi. The only problem is that it stops working sometimes, and doesn't resume for minutes or sometimes hours. I only have this problem on my laptop, and not on my phone. Even if I turn 3G off on the phone and leave Wi-Fi on, it still works fine while my laptop cannot connect.

When it stops working, the SSID is still visible when searching for networks, but Google Chrome reports a DNS error and when I try to ping any URL or even an IP address in the terminal, it times out. OS X's built in network diagnostics cannot fix the problem. I don't think it is a hardware issue with my laptop because when it goes down, I can tether my phone via Wi-Fi and it works fine.

Comment: hows your signal strength?  are you getting assigned a DHCP address?

Comment: The RSSI is -51.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem, it was a bug in Mac OS X Lion and was resolved by updating once Apple fixed it. Similar bugs were in OS X Yosemite and were fixed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

It could be the security type they're using.  I've come across laptops that have serious issues with WEP encryption and setting the network to WPA resolved it.
Is there a possibility of changing the security on their AP?

If not, maybe you could ask if they have bandwidth restrictions in place...   If you laptop connects and starts to do some major Windows online updates (or you have a virus that is using the internet connection), you may be temporarily restricted?

**EDIT:-**   You could also take note of the IP address, gateway and DNS servers your laptop or phone aquires via DHCP and then manually input similar.

ie.  let's assume you aquire IP: 192.168.1.14, SM: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.1.254, PDNS: 192.168.1.254...   You could turn off DHCP and set the IP to 192.168.1.99, the same SM, GW and PDNS as before.   If it is stable now, we can assume that their wireless access point (AP) may have lease issues with your laptop.  If it is still unstable, you could change the PDNS (primary DNS) and secondary DNS to known good public DNS (eg.google - 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.4, or OpenDNS - 208.67.222.222 and 208.67.222.220).

If everything is working OK using the manual IP, SM, GW and two external public DNS records, then it could be that the AP is having DNS issues.

Comment: There is no security, the network is open. (there's a redirect that asks for your room number and last name)

Comment: and does the laptop work without issue on other wireless networks?